# how to compress the file using python gzip module to retain original timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x

In linux , by default gzip command will preserve the timestamp of original filename and original file will be compressed with same timestamp.
But In python , gzip module creates new file with current timestamp . how to preserve the timestamp of original filename for compressed file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36034315/2836621

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about timestamp in linux gzip CLI tool and Python Gzip module, but you can execute shell commands in Python runtime, maybe you can do this:

```
import os

os.system("gzip [OPTION]... [FILE]...")
```